# Apache GUI for request's details like Ngrok interface

Tags: apache, user-interface, request, ngrok

I need to see the details of the requests sent on my server, for that Ngrok works well with its interface I can see the header of the requests, the data sent and the response of the server in its entirety.

I am looking for something similar but for apache.
Here is an image of the Ngrok interface
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilVkh.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tarlaros have you look around Web Debugging Proxy • HTTP Monitor / HTTP Proxy / HTTPS & SSL Proxy / Reverse Proxy like :

- multi mitmproxy ;
- on osx you have Charles ;
- on linux you have Camilla.